# Object define property: How to set requestAnimationFrame to false?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How to set `requestAnimationFrame` to `false` what would be tested in conditional statement?

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'requestAnimationFrame', {
    value: ()=> {}
})


//need to be tested

if ('requestAnimationFrame' in window === false) {
            window.scroll(0, destinationOffsetToScroll)
            if (callback) {
                callback()
            }
            return
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your code is invalid javascript (`return` outside of a function body). Maybe we can help if you give more context.

Comment: @NicolasBrugneaux
this return is ok, because if `if ('requestAnimationFrame' in window === false)` performed then i stop my method works. This condition works inside method

Comment: As you're currently presenting the code, the syntax is invalid, if you don't give more context as asked, we can't help you out so much. Can you explain what your goal is? why would you set window.requestAnimationFrame to be false?

Comment: @NicolasBrugneaux because i need to test this in jest. Then tests running, then globals like `window, document` should be mocked to work with tests. Because it not work with browser

Comment: Makes sense. please check out my answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you indicated in your comments, you're trying to mock
>   window.requestanimationframe behaviour. I'd suggest having a look at
>   https://github.com/alexreardon/raf-stub or
>   https://github.com/FormidableLabs/mock-raf :)

Edit:

```
delete window.requestAnimationFrame;
'requestAnimationFrame' in window === false
// true
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: No, i need to do this by `Object.defineProperty` :)

Comment: all I want is for the condition to be met `if ('requestAnimationFrame' in window === false)`

Comment: why you receive  answer not useful if it's useful? :D